# Catching a runtime exception in PHP

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to catch a runtime exception that will be thrown by a function that is basically just a wrapper function for oci_execute(). For example:

```
try {   
    $SQL = "INSERT";
    ExecuteQuery($SQL);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<p>There was an error.</p>";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

However, the exception doesn't appear to be caught:

```
...
ociexecute() [function.ociexecute]: ORA-00925: missing INTO keyword
...
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your `ExecuteQuery` function really throwing an exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like it's triggering an error rather than throwing an exception.

You could convert errors to exceptions using [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) - something like this:

```
function errorHandler($number, $string, $file = 'Unknown', $line = 0, $context = array())
{
    if (($number == E_NOTICE) || ($number == E_STRICT))
        return false;

    if (!error_reporting())
        return false;

    throw new Exception($string, $number);

    return true;
}

set_error_handler('errorHandler');
```

Comment: If you want to convert errors into exceptions you may want to take a look at PHP's own ErrorException: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

Comment: You are awesome Greg.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like an Exception, more like a plain PHP error.

If it is, check if you have eAccelerator and what version you have. I had a problem a while ago, there was eAccelerator bug that didn't catch Exception and I had to turn it off :|